# Is there a way to program in c# such that when an exe runs, it serves and handles requests on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, webserver

I want to make a program that hosts a webpage with computer uptime of the system it is running on but I don't want to do anything to the user's IIS. Is there anyway to do by making some system calls (to the ISAPI dlls etc) in c#?

Comment: Often I wish SO would allow question authors to pick multiple answers as valid; thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create a web server?

Try [System.Net.HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)

You can get the system's uptime in milliseconds using [System.Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the HTTPListener class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just serve the page yourself - a simple web server is not hard to write and there are a lot of examples available on the net; from extremely simple to quite advanced. For example [this](http://webserver.codeplex.com/) one.

Answer (score 1):

If an alternative to IIS you seek, give [Cassinni](http://ultidev.com/Products/Cassini/) a try.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been answered, [HTTPListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) is a good start.

However, you're quickly going to discover issues with firewalls and available ports, so ultimately I think you'll find that *doing something to the user's IIS* is likely the path of least resistance, at least on systems where IIS is already running.

If IIS isn't an option then you will either need the app itself or an installer to configure Windows Firewall to allow incoming connections. They also may have other software and hardware Firewalls in place which need configured.